# How do I redirect to different page with same option selected?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, drop-down-menu

Ok. So, I have a simple dropdown menu in my page's footer in which I need to select an option, redirect to my contact page and have the same option selected in my contact form.

There's an example at https://nexia.com, but I would like a cleaner solution than what is there. I also need to be able to do this in javascript, just selecting the option without modifying the url.

What I've been able to do so far is to have the form redirect onsubmit to the correct page. The only step left is to return the same selected value that was submitted.

This is the HTML:

```
<form id="selectForm">
  <div class="select-wrap">
     <div class="select-container">
       <select>
        <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">How can we help?</option>
        <option value="enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
        <option value="audit">Audit</option>
        <option value="tax">Tax</option>
        <option value="advisory">Advisory</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div>
    <input class="btn btn--dark" id="submit" type="submit" value="Ask Us">
</form>
```

This is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

          var select = document.getElementById('selectForm')

          window.onload=function() {
          select.onsubmit=function() {
            window.location.replace("/contact");
            return false;
          }
        }

</script>
```

Need a hand with the next step.

For further clarification, if the option 'Audit' is selected in the footer form, on submit I want the user redirected to '/contact' and the contact form's selected option to be 'Audit', as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.getElementById('selectForm')
    window.onload = function () {
        if (getCookie("selection")) {
            document.getElementById("help_option").value = getCookie("selection");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("help_option").value = "default";
        }
        select.onsubmit = function () {
            document.cookie = "selection=" + (document.getElementById("help_option").value);
            return false;
        }
    }
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
</script>
```

```html
<form id="selectForm">
    <div class="select-wrap">
        <div class="select-container">
            <select id="help_option">
                <option value="default" selected="true" disabled="disabled">How can we help?</option>
                <option value="enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
                <option value="audit">Audit</option>
                <option value="tax">Tax</option>
                <option value="advisory">Advisory</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn--dark" id="submit" type="submit" value="Ask Us">
</form>
```

When you submit the form, you store the selected value into a cookie. After that you redirect to your contact page. On window.onload you can read the value of the set cookie and then set that as the value of your selection in the contact page.
I added the standart getCookie method from w3schools in order to make it easier to read the cookie. [w3school js-cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Should this work with something like this: document.querySelector('[id*="help_option"]').id? The contact form adds a prefix to the selected option. So, id="form1_help_option"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in browser context you use localStorage for sharing data across the pages.

Just before navigating to the other page, use `localStorage.setItem("key", "value");`

And onLoad of new page `localStorage.getItem("key");` to read this value.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work, but I started reading up it since you've highlighted it. Most probably, would like to try it for my next project. Thanks.